# VLSM, Rip V1 and Rip V2

Tags: rip, vlsm

I am trying to understand some things about Rip V1 and V2 but I'm not sure if I'm right,

As I know Rip V1 doesn't **"advertise"** subnet masks, and doesn't support VLSM.
If i understand right **Even** if Rip V1 for **example** supports VLSM it doesn't matter, Becouse the Rip V1 **Only "advertise"** the IP address, If some one can please confirm/expand/correct me I will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RIPv1 is a classfull routing protocol and it do not send the subnet mask when it sends updates. and when a router running RIPv1 receives an update it reacts by one of the following actions:

- If the router has a directly connected interface belonging to the same major network, it will apply the same subnet mask as that interface.
- If the router does not have any interfaces belonging to the same major network, it will apply the classful subnet mask to the route.

Comment: Hey BluesRhythm and thank you for your answer, Please take a look at this link:http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=CCIE_Practical_Studies_I&seqNum=104

Comment: hey @uBlankText thanks for the link i ran back to one of my old books to refresh my memory and edited the answer to be accurate

Comment: Anytime BluesRhythm, Thank you for your help, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in your understanding. RIPv1 supports only classfull routing. RIPv2 supports VLSM.